# How do i authenticate my Oauth credentials for the youtube API?

Tags: python, google-api, youtube-api, google-oauth, youtube-data-api

I've spend hours going in circles because I can't seem to find whats going wrong on my end. I'm trying to use the youtube api to get information on my videos that I've posted on my channel. However, I can't seem to get past authenticating myself. I'm using Oauth2.0 and I'm like 95% sure I've configured the credentials and consent things on google cloud correctly. I've tried other people's code and all of them give the same error, that I'm missing a valid API key. I have a couple of ideas to why its happening but my main theory is that the api documentation is kinda outdated and so maybe i jumbled up my code. Or im simply not passing the credentials parameter properly.. i have no idea.

```
    import os
    from google.auth.transport.requests import Request
    from google.oauth2.credentials import Credentials
    from google_auth_oauthlib.flow import InstalledAppFlow
    from googleapiclient.discovery import build
    from googleapiclient.errors import HttpError
    from google.oauth2 import service_account

    credentials_file = 'credentials.json'
    SCOPES = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube.readonly']

    def main():
        credentials = None
        if os.path.exists('token.json'):
            credentials = Credentials.from_authorized_user_file('token.json', SCOPES)
        if not credentials or not credentials.valid:
            if credentials and credentials.expired and credentials.refresh_token:
                credentials.refresh(Request())
            else:
                flow = InstalledAppFlow.from_client_secrets_file('credentials.json', SCOPES)
                credentials = flow.run_local_server(port=8080)
            with open('token.json', 'w') as token:
                token.write(credentials.to_json())
        
   
        youtube = build('youtube', 'v3', credentials=credentials)
        youtube.search().list(
            forMine=True,
            type='video',
            part='id',
            #channelId='left blank for example'
         ).execute()
    if __name__ == "__main__":
        main()
```

This is the script, i don't think the issue is specific to this script though since the same thing happened when i tried other's.

here is my error:

```
googleapiclient.errors.HttpError: <HttpError 403 when requesting
```

heres the message i get in my browser

```
    {
      "error": {
        "code": 403,
        "message": "The request is missing a valid API key.",
        "errors": [
          {
            "message": "The request is missing a valid API key.",
            "domain": "global",
            "reason": "forbidden"
          }
        ],
        "status": "PERMISSION_DENIED"
      }``your text``
    }`your text`
```

If anyone has any tips please let me know!